# How to enable other people's Android phone to use the test version of your unreleased Google Action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing a Google Action for Google Assistant and it is not yet a state where I can release. Even so I want it to be available for some tester, and in a near future, my client.

The simulator with the "test" is somewhat limited at auth request, name recognition (since it will only knows my action) and experience (to show my client), so I prefer not to depend on it for this case.

I found it is only possible to interact with a test version of an action if the project owner's account is logged in as a Google account in the phone where you want to call the action. Is it correct? Or there is another way?

I even tried adding my wife's Google account as a viewer to the project, but I am unable to call my action from her phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add people as a viewer to the project. Before those users can call your action on any of their devices, they will need to use the test console at https://console.actions.google.com/ once, this will enable testing on their device. After that they will be able to interact with your action on their devices.

Do note, the time in which the action is available on their account is limited by a time period (about a couple of months). If they cant access the action any more after a couple of months, just repeat the above step to reactivate testing for their account.

---

**Update**

One thing that you could consider in the two approached posted by @Prisoner and me is if your testers need to test on just a device or need access to the console as well. Using the approach from @Prisoner will allow your users to test on devices. The above approach will also allow testers to use the console at https://console.actions.google.com/.

Comment: I did not know the need to use the simutalor. But since it asks the user to accept terms and conditions, now it makes sense!
I now the tester have access to the application. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jordi's answer, you can also do an [Alpha Release](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases#setup) of your Action. This lets you permit up to 20 additional accounts to the released version

Once you permit them using the console, you will send them the opt-in URL, which they should visit on a mobile device with that account. Once they have opted into the Alpha, they can activate it using the regular trigger phrase.

Comment: I did not know this was possible. It will be a better experience to show the action to my client. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This still isn't working for me in 2022. I have enabled Alpha and added testers, but when they open the link in the Assistant app, a blank page with an error appears and they are unable to opt-in.
EDIT: this approach does not work for Smart Home actions

Comment: Correct, Smart Home actions are a very different creature with their own release and control method (and a method that is changing as Matter comes online).